# localization Faker\Factory does not work in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a Post Model with these fields :

```
post_id
post_title
post_content
post_content_full
author
```

Now I want to use laravel sedders and model factories to create fake `fa_IR` localized data and insert to `posts` table.

For that I wrote this in `database/factories/ModelFactory.php`:

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
        return [
            'post_title'        => $faker->sentence,
            'post_content'      => $faker->paragraph,
            'post_content_full' => $faker->paragraph(3),
            'author'            => $faker->name
        ];
    });
```

Then I created a `PostsTableSeeder` class like this :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PostsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run ()
    {
        factory(App\Post::class, 5)->create();
    }
}
```

And in `AppServiceProvider.php` added below codes to `register` function :

```
$this->app->singleton(FakerGenerator::class, function () {
        return FakerFactory::create('fa_IR');
    });
```

But After running the seed , laravel uses default locale (`en_US`) and ignores  `fa_IR`.

I do not know what else to do.

**Update:**

Even I changed in `DEFAULT_LOCALE` const `vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Factory.php` to `fa_IR` Nothing changed.

Comment: Could you try using the `->address()` method?, could be the case that the functions you are using are not supported in the `fa_IR` language

Comment: Yes, it worked when use address. did it mean that `paraphraph` is not supported in `fa_IR` language?

Comment: Yep, sadly that is right, i think its possible to customize paragraph but that doesn't seem very handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all faker methods are supported in every language, from what a quick lookup of the documentation says, the `Company` and `Address` provider are supported in the `fa_IR` localization

Comment: Where can I find which providers are supported?

Comment: @A.B.Developer [here](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#language-specific-formatters)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
$factory->define(App\Post::class, function () {
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create('fa_IR');

    return [
        'post_title'        => $faker->sentence,
        'post_content'      => $faker->paragraph,
        'post_content_full' => $faker->paragraph(3),
        'author'            => $faker->name
    ];
});
```

Comment: It has same result.

Comment: you may follow this https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/tree/master/src/Faker/Provider/fa_IR

Comment: There is a `text` provider but when I use `text()` method, it uses default localization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the faker locale in your app config file.

Answer (score 0):

First run this

```
php artisan make:factory PostFactory
```

Do like this

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
```

Then use like this

```
    $sub_g->name = $faker->name();
    $sub_g->country = $faker->country();
    $sub_g->state = $faker->state;
```

Thank me later.